# issue merging two Javascript object arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an object array. I just want to add one more object "WITH" an index. I'm not sure how it's done.

This is what I've tried:

```
//RAW DATA:
this.fetchedData = [{
  "startMinute": 0, //Remove
  "annotation": "All Day",
  "twelveHourFormat": "12am-11:59pm", //Remove
  "timeRange": "00:00-23:59",
  "endMinute": 1439 //Remove
}, {
  "startMinute": 300, //Remove
  "annotation": "Morning",
  "twelveHourFormat": "5am-8:59am", //Remove
  "timeRange": "05:00-08:59",
  "endMinute": 539 //Remove
}]

var newTimeRanges = [];
var temp = []; //Final array(assuming i need one)

newTimeRanges = _.each(this.fetchedData, function(time) {
  delete time.startMinute;
  delete time.twelveHourFormat;
  delete time.endMinute;
});

//DATA AFTER REMOVAL

newTimeRanges = {
  0: {
    annotation: "All Day",
    timeRange: "00:00-23:59"
  },
  1: {
    annotation: "Evening",
    timeRange: "16:00-18:00"
  }
}

//DATA TO BE MERGED
var dirtyData = [{
  "timeRange": "3am-6am",
  "annotation": earlymorning
}];

//Essentially (timeRange+DirtyData)


//Expected Output to be sent for backend
{
  "times": [{
      "annotation": "All Day",
      "timeRange": "00:00-23:59"
    }, {
      "annotation": "Morning",
      "timeRange": "05:00-08:59"
    },
    //Add my new Data here
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to add or remove another object to that array.

```
temp.push(newTimeRanges);
temp.push(dirtyData);
```

This does not merge the records. Instead creates two objects one object and another array.

**How can I merge. newTimeRanges with DirtyData.** (Like I want 3: "Object")

**Is there any efficient way of doing this?**

Thanks

Comment: why not `temp=newTimeRanges; temp.push(dirtyData[0]);//or loop through it`

Comment: please add the raw data and the wanted result, like an object literal.

Comment: `newTimeRanges` started as an array, but when you logged it it became an object. How did you populate it?

Comment: Why are you initializing `newTimeRanges` with an empty array if you're just going to immediately replace it with an object?

Comment: @Barmar when I used underscoreJS loop to go through the loop and remove few things that converted to object. I had to delete bunch of stuff and store it back. Now I want to append to the newly created object.

Comment: @Barmar I tried initializing as an object. But that doesn't help me either.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't use the right functions in underscoreJS. It should be able to create an array.

Comment: @TechnoCorner You don't need to initialize it at all if you're just going to reassign it with something else.

Comment: According to the underscoreJS documentation, `_.each()` returns the original array. I don't see how it's getting turned into an object from that.

Comment: I think it's array of objects? @Barmar

Comment: Your question shows an object of objects, not an array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push each property of `newTimeRanges` separately onto the `temp` array. Then you can concatenate `dirtyData`.

```
$.each(newTimeRanges, function(key, obj) {
    temp.push(obj);
}
temp = temp.concat(dirtyData);
```

Or you could have made `newTimeRanges` an array instead of an object, and then you could write:

```
newTimeRanges = [
    {
        annotation:"All Day",
        timeRange:"00:00-23:59"},
    {
        annotation:"Evening",
        timeRange:"16:00-18:00"}
];

temp = newTimeRanges.concat(dirtyData);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge 2 arrays into a third array you must use concat, like this:

```
var temp = newTimeRanges.concat(dirtyData);
```

See: [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Changing your code to work:

```
//RAW DATA:
var fetchedData = [{
  "startMinute": 0, //Remove
  "annotation": "All Day",
  "twelveHourFormat": "12am-11:59pm", //Remove
  "timeRange": "00:00-23:59",
  "endMinute": 1439 //Remove
}, {
  "startMinute": 300, //Remove
  "annotation": "Morning",
  "twelveHourFormat": "5am-8:59am", //Remove
  "timeRange": "05:00-08:59",
  "endMinute": 539 //Remove
}];

fetchedData.forEach(function(time) {
  delete time.startMinute;
  delete time.twelveHourFormat;
  delete time.endMinute;
});

console.log(fetchedData);

//DATA TO BE MERGED
var dirtyData = [{
  "timeRange": "3am-6am",
  "annotation": "earlymorning"
}];

var temp = fetchedData.concat(dirtyData);

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: @Barmar The question is about arrays... Or it should be.

Comment: It should be, but read the question. He's replacing the array with an object that happens to have numeric property names. But it's not an array.

Comment: Yeah, he is changing it as we speak, so I'm sticking to the title, since it seems that he is just lost with the code.

Comment: I mean, it seems that he can accomplish what he wants using arrays.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I got it to work! Sorry, If i confused you guys!